# How can I change change any column datetime format if my Jquery datatable has dynamic data/columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to iterate over my 'col' variable that contains all data for dynamic datatable and change datetime format if any column data consis date type. Some columns are permanent to the table but some are dynamic (can have dynamic header names).  Please provide me with some suggestions , Ideas and examples.
Added my datatable code below please have a look.

'col' contains this -> {data: "Id", name: "", visible: false},{data: "Id", name: "", visible: false },{data: "Name", name: "Name", visible: true}, {data: "Description", name: "Description", visible: true}

```js
 table = $('#tblId').DataTable({
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "filter": true,
                        "orderMulti": false,
                        "destroy": true,
                        "scrollX": true,
                        "sProcessing": '@L("LOADER_INFO_MESSAGE")',
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController")',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "datatype": "json"
                        },
                        "columns": col,  //col contains all data
                     
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "searchable": false,
                            "orderable": false,
                            "targets": 0
                        }],
                       
                        },
                      
                    });
```

```html
<table id='tblId'>
</table>
```

Comment: Please give us some examples of what the `col` variable can contain.

Comment: wait giving....

Comment: it contains   {data: "Id", name: "", visible: false},{data: "Id", name: "", visible: false },{data: "Name", name: "Name", visible: true}, {data: "Description", name: "Description", visible: true}

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62909020/edit) the question and put the data in it. So, when creating the `col` variable, you know which one is datetime, am I right?

Comment: No  , fields are created dynamically ,fieldnames can change even fielddata can also changed by user.

Comment: Can we iterate through this and create a new array after changes during iterations? @PriyankPanchal

Comment: The data you gave is invalid for the datatables `columns` key. It expects the data in a particular format, please check https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns for details. As you mentioned, you will have to iterate through your data and generate expected input. Else, you can use [Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) Then you can use [renderers](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)